# Google Protocol Buffers Vs JSON: C++ to C# communication

Tags: c#, c++, json, sockets, protocol-buffers

I have two applications which communicate via TCP socket. For the time being, these applications are both local but in the future, the server application will run on the cloud (Amazon EC2 Instance).

The Server application is written in `C++`
The Client application is written in `C#`

I am sending an object from server to client that has the following properties:

```
Guid Id
uint8* ImageData
```

Although, I may wish to add extra properties in the future. However, I will try to keep this object as minimal as possible as latency is important here.

Now, I am currently using JSON to communicate between programs, but I was wondering about Google Protocol Buffers (GPB) because, while JSON is nice and east to work with, plus is human-readable, it does have a large overhead and from the looks of things, is causing a noticeable delay in the communications.

What I am looking for, is a more efficient method to communicate between Client and Server applications.

How do GPB's compare with JSON? Has anyone had any experience with high-performance use of GPB? Are there any other protocols which may be better suited here?

Comment: Google protocol buffers are optimized to save bandwidth. JSON is (because it's text oriented) pretty bad from this point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These references will help you.

https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/md__benchmarks.html

https://capnproto.org/news/2014-06-17-capnproto-flatbuffers-sbe.html

There is a C++ implementation for converting JSON to/from protobuf on [github](https://github.com/shramov/json2pb).

Comment: Thank you, those links are exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There're many things that we don't know:

- How big is `uint8* ImageData` usually?
- How do you serialise binary data to JSON
- What's available bandwidth
- What's an average and expected data rate

What I'm trying to say is that you need to worry about JSON overhead only if it matters, otherwise why to change anything. You mentioned latency, but it would be affected only if you had more data to send than your available bandwidth.

For your extremely simple case I wouldn't even use JSON but serialise it manually into binary blob, except you expect in the future your protocol will evolve significantly.

Comment: Thanks, @AndyT. `ImageData` is usually about 1mb is size. About `bandwidth`, could you tell me how I can calculate my available bandwidth?

Comment: you can calculate it by www.speedtest.net. 1MB is big enough to not worry about JSON overhead at all, it doesn't matter what your bandwidth is

Comment: if you use base64 encoding to put your image data into JSON, you have ~33% of overhead here, so you can worry about this if you're billed a fortune for your outgoing bandwidth

Comment: I am more concerned about latency - not really about cost. I am trying to get the data from the server to the client as fast as possible.

Comment: Latency would increase only if you reached your bandwidth limitation, until then your latency is mainly dictated by speed of light. Let's suppose you have limited bandwidth. Each your "packet" consists of 1MB image data (1.33 if base64 encoded) and ~100 bytes of JSON stuff. You can eliminate JSON overhead completely and get  0.01% of improvement of your data rate. Is it worth the effort?